# How to work around "OGR-failure while deleting field 13. Invalid field index"?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, editing

this post might be related to this one:

[QGIS Field Calculator Results Removed When Saving Edits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57051/qgis-field-calculator-results-removed-when-saving-edits)

---

But there is

1. no suitable answer for me
2. It is not allowed to ask another time in the other post I guess so I created a new one.

---

I have got a Shapefile with all boroughs in France (projection = EPSG:2154 - RGF93 / Lambert-93)
I like to add some columns: area, Population, average income. The answer to make the columns bigger for area calculation does not work because the maximum size seems to be 10 in my Qgis version (1.8 Lisboa). If I like to add simply numbers (population number for example that does not work either. It does not matter if I use "interger" "real" or "string"...while saving it tells me that saving did not work because it was not able to delete attributes. OGR-failure while deleting field 13. Invalid field index

Afterwards the result seems to be different: sometimes it can save the result, sometimes there will be set "NULL". It can not be so difficult to add a column in a shapefile can it?

To show you what I am working with 2 screenshots (I added the last 2 columns):

[image: failure]

[image: results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem was caused by a too long headline. Without this long head line it seems to work.
But I am still carefull and I save after entering 4-5 lines just to make sure not to waste another day by editing...

Comment: If you work with shapefiles, you should avoid column names with more than 10 characters. And better don't use blanks in header names.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is always the same: You know it but at the end you can not remember it ;) My names are all connected with "_" or "-" but i forgot the head lines...